# Set AppDelegate.scpt in Xcode 5 to Run-Only

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

I am trying to hide the code within the AppDelegate.scpt of my Cocoa-Applescript project when it is built. When I create a script in AppleScript Editor, I am able to select the "Run-Only" option to limit a persons ability to view the code. I want to mimic this behavior so that users of my application cannot view the code in AppDelegate.scpt.

Can anyone recommend how I can compile AppDelegate.scpt or set it to "Run-only" so that users cannot see the code?

Answer (score 0):

While in Xcode, select the top level in the Navigator > Build Settings and scroll down to OSACompile - Build Options and set "Save as Execute-Only" to Yes